# /dev/kvm permission denied in vnc session

Tags: permissions, virtual-machine, kvm, vnc

How can I get virtualization (KVM) to work in non-local VNC sessions? I am getting a permission denied error, on /dev/kvm. Everything works outside of VNC fine. KVM is apparently required for android simulation.

**Client Connection Info:**
This SHOULD NOT matter, other than it not being "localhost"... I think.
I am connecting through VNC using the client, `remmina`, on a arm64 chromebook running `cruiton` with ubuntu 16.04. The VNC session was started using display 15 (`vncserver :15`).

**terminal info from android studio:**

```
$ studio.sh
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":15".
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@6d5380c2 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/home/user/opt/androidstudio/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/user/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/tmp/jna4741585790560209208.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/user/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/tmp/jna4741585790560209208.tmp
[  12641]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/StudioDownloaderaddon2-1.xml (No such file or directory) 
[  12738]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/user/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  18440]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Unable to find language kind for files with extension 'c', assuming it as 'C'
```

**contents of `.vnc/xstartup`:**

```
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
def
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
startxfce4 &
```

How do I fix this?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/5468694

Answer (score 1):

Using root for this is a bad idea. Add your user to the `kvm` group, logout (all sessions) and login and you should be fine.